# Manipulating very large binary strings in c#

Tags: c#, string, binary

I'm working on a genetic algorithm project where I encode my chromosome in a binary string where each 32 bits represents a value. The problem is that the functions I'm optimizing has over 3000 parameters which implies that I have over 96000 bits in my bit string and the manipulations i do on this are simply to slow...

I have proceeded as following: I have a binary class where I'm creating a boolean array that represents my big binary string. Then I manipulate this binary string with various shifts and moves and such.

My question is, is there a better way to do this? The speed is just killing. I'm sure it would be fine if i only did this on one bit string but i have to do the manipulations on 25 bit strings for way over 1000 generations.

Comment: Chunky, intensive operations like this where speed is key may benefit from a non-managed (native) approach - e.g. a C++ library.  However, it would be of great benefit for this question to see some sample code/data/operations.

Comment: What do you mean by binary string? Are you using a byte[]? Or an int[] or some similar structure? If so, those operations, even with 96k bits, should be very fast. If you're actually using a textual string, that's obviously the root of the perf problem.

Comment: I'm not using a textual string, I'm using an bool[] array. So it should be fast indeed. To give a sample of an operation suppose i have the following bool array: {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i} (where all letters are either true or false) then an operation might do an insert after b of the bool values {x,y,z} so that my array now looks like {a,b,x,y,z,c,d,e,f}. This takes forever on long arrays...

Comment: @Erik: Have you considered SQL server for something like this?  This is a great deal of set-based operations you are performing, and SQL server could probably do it *much* faster than any procedural code you could write.

Comment: @casperOne: Wouldn't the communication between my program and the SQL server create a huge bottle neck?

Comment: @Erik: You could easily load the data into your database through bulk import.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I would do is take a step back. Your analysis seems to be wedded to an implementation detail, namely that you have chosen bool[] as how you represent a string of bits.

Clear your mind of bools and arrays and make a *complete* list of the operations you actually need to perform, how frequently they happen, and how fast they have to be. Ideally consider whether your speed requirement is *average speed* or *worst case speed*. (There are many data structures that attain high average speed by having one expensive operation for every thousand cheap operations; if having *any* expensive operations is unacceptable then you need to know that up front.)

Once you have that list, you can then do research on what data structures work well.

For example, suppose your list of operations is:

- construct bit sequences on the order of 32 bits
- concatenate on the order of 3000 bit sequences together to form new bit sequences
- insert new bit sequences into existing long bit sequences at specific locations, quickly

Given just that list of operations, I'd think that the data structure you want is a **catenable deque**. Catenable deques support fast insertion on either end, and can be broken up into two deques efficiently. Inserting stuff into the middle of a deque is then easily done: break the deque up, insert the item into the end of one half, and join them back up again.

However, if you then add another operation to the problem, say, "search for a particular bit string anywhere in the 90000-bit sequence, **and find the result in sublinear time**" then just a catenable deque isn't going to do it. Searching a deque is slow. There are other data structures that support that operation.

Comment: This is very interesting, I do not have to search my sequence and as a matter of fact all my operations can be executed by some smart splitting/inserting at end/start combinations... I will definitively read up on catenable deque structures!!

Comment: @Erik: I have a simple immutable deque implementation on my blog that you can use; no warranty expressed or implied, I have not tested it. It does not implement the "split in the middle" feature; that is left as an exercise. :-) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/12/immutability-in-c-part-eleven-a-working-double-ended-queue.aspx This series of articles was based on a paper on finger trees: http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/FingerTree.pdf see it for details of how to construct a deque that can be efficiently split apart and put back together.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance; is a catenable deque simply implemented by a doubly-linked list, or is there a trick in there that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @configurator: A doubly-linked list makes an excellent *mutable* catenable deque but a lousy *immutable* catenable deque because there is no way to build the data structure in such a way that it is *persistent*. That is, you can't re-use parts of an immutable doubly-linked list to make another one, the way you can with a singly-linked list.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly you are encoding the bit array in a `bool[]`. The first obvious optimisation would be to change this to `int[]` (or even `long[]`) and take advantage of bit operations on a whole machine word, where possible.

For example, this would make shifts more efficient by ~ a factor 4.

Comment: This would be possible but I have operations where I have to insert k bits which at a specific index which causes all the bits to the right of the index to shift by k (to the right). I don't think I could do such a thing on a int[] or long[] since i could only split at each 32 bit or 64 bit resp. and then have to shift by either 32 or 64 bits... Thoughts?

Comment: @Erik Sure you can. You simply have to implement bit shifting by arbitrary amounds manually for your whole bit array. You *should* do that, it’s bound to be the most efficient.

Comment: Say i have an int 623 = 1001101111. Now how would i go about extracting 1101 from 100[1101]111 without first converting 623 back to bool[] array or bit representation?

Comment: @Erik So the result should be `100[]111`, with `[]` being the place where the value was extracted? Well, how would you do it for normal bit vectors (= integers)? You Mask the remaining two parts (100 and 111) via bit masks and bitwise-and, you copy the higher bits (100), shift them three places to the right, you paste them onto the lower order bits (111) via bitwise-or. Now you need to implement bitwise-or, bitwise-and and bit-shifting for your BitVector structure.

Comment: Since I'm not super familiar with the performance difference of these operations to what I want to do I have to ask, how much of a difference would such a set up have in terms of performance compared to what I'm doing now (simply moving every bool up by 4). It seems like you're adding a lot of operations, would it still be faster?

Comment: @Erik in your specific case that really depends and I can’t judge without measuring but it may be *a lot* faster. In general, the reason to use bit operations in the first place is that they perform *much* faster than conventional operations (because they allow doing up to 32 operations in parallel), that’s called bit parallelism. Moving elements in an array requires a lot of copying and is very slow. With shifts, this may reduce the need to copy and be a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

Is the [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3we7ff2.aspx) class no help?

Comment: I believe a BitArray is exactly what I've implemented, an bool[] array representing a binary string.

Comment: BitArray only behaves like a bool[] array - it's not a bool array

Answer (score 0):

A `BitArray` would probably be faster than a boolean array but you would still not get built-in support to shift 96000 bits.

GPUs are extremely good at massive bit operations. Maybe [Brahma](http://brahma.ananthonline.net/), [CUDA.NET](http://www.hoopoe-cloud.com/Solutions/CUDA.NET/Default.aspx), or [Accelerator](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Accelerator/) could be of service?

Comment: hmm indeed, now if only I had experience with using a GPU for calculations... Maybe worth the time to learn?

Comment: Probably; GPUs are being leveraged for a lot of "embarassingly parallel" algorithms other than graphics manipulation, such as encryption cracking. If we're talking about a LOT of very simple operations, it's perfect.

Comment: I will definitively read up on this, if I'm lucky it might be what I need. thanks!

Comment: GPUs are unfortunately quite bad at “cheap” operations since copying a lot of data is comparably expensive and is only amortised by the fact that the GPU can perform parallel computations really fast. But bit operations are fast anyway so there’s not much gained this way, and once you start nonlocal operations (such as deleting bits, see above) SIMD requires quite complex operations.

Comment: @Konrad there's a very good chance that you're right but it's kind of hard to know with the vague problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Let me understand; currently, you're using a sequence of 32-bit values for a "chromosome". Are we talking about DNA chromosomes or neuroevolutionary algorithmic chromosomes?

If it's DNA, you deal with 4 values; A,C,G,T. That can be coded in 2 bits, making a byte able to hold 4 values. Your 3000-element chromosome sequence can be stored in a 750-element byte array; that's nothing, really.

Your two most expensive operations are to and from the compressed bitstream. I would recommend a byte-keyed enum:

```
public enum DnaMarker : byte { A, C, G, T };
```

Then, you go from 4 of these to a byte with one operation:

```
public static byte ToByteCode(this DnaMarker[] markers)
{
   byte output = 0;
   for(byte i=0;i<4;i++)
      output = (output << 2) + (byte)markers[i];
}
```

... and parse them back out with something like this:

```
public static DnaMarker[] ToMarkers(this byte input)
{
   var result = new byte[4];
   for(byte i=0;i<4;i++)
       result[i] = (DnaMarker)(input - (input >> (2*(i+1))));

   return result;
}
```

You might see a slight performance increase using four parameters (output if necessary) versus allocating and using an array in the heap. But, you lose the iteration which makes the code more compact.

Now, because you're packing them into four-byte "blocks", if your sequence length isn't always an exact multiple of four you'll end up "padding" the end of your block with zero values (A). Working around this is messy, but if you had a 32-bit integer that told you the exact number of markers, you can simply discard anything more you find in the bytestream.

From here, possibilities are endless; you can convert the enum array to a string by simply calling ToString() on each one, and likewise you can feed in a string and get an enum array by iterating through using Enum.Parse().

And always remember, unless memory is at a premium (usually it isn't), it's almost always faster to deal with the data in an easily-usable format instead of the most compact format. The one big exception is in network transmission; if you had to send 750 bytes vs 12KB over the Internet, there's an obvious advantage in the smaller size.

Comment: Of course this is possible it is simply a mater of moving from a base-2 representation system to a base-4 system. I would rather stick with the base-2 system since it allows for more deep changes in the genetic code and since all computers are base-2 systems.

Comment: I think you’re misunderstanding the problem. A “genetic algorithm” is only a metaphor (though a very apt one). There’s in general no compelling reason to model the problem using DNA bases. The point isn’t so much modelling biological DNA; rather, it’s the problem of modelling random mutation, recombination and nonrandom selection.